# VSCode XML Language Basics suggestions (intellisense) implementation

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

Anyone knows how is it implemented? I'd like use it as base for an xml extension test. Digging in VSCode sources on github i found syntax, brackets an higlight management (mostly via regex), but I cannot understand how suggestions are implemented (the proposed suggestions are tags, attributes and attribute values found in the document).

Answer (score 2):

VS Code provides rich support for language features based on the [language server protocol (LSP)](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/). So, if a VS Code extension starts a process implementing the LSP for XML, you can get things like [auto-completion](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_completion), [hover](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_hover), [linting](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_publishDiagnostics) and more.

Red Hat provides the [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) extension, which itself runs [Eclipse LemMinX](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx), a Java-based implementation of the LSP for XML. The entry point for its implementation of completion support can be found [here](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/blob/022615e0c9fb2cf7af12b1ad29a16380a2768a04/org.eclipse.lemminx/src/main/java/org/eclipse/lemminx/XMLTextDocumentService.java#L186-L193).

As of vscode-xml 0.15.0, you don't need Java anymore to run it. You still get extremely advanced XML support from within VS Code, with validation and tag completion based on XSD schema for instance.

Comment: Seems a very complete solution: I'll take a look. thank you